# In the YouTube API, is there a way to get the default channel access controls?

Tags: youtube-api

I'm trying to figure out how to get the accessControl defaults for a channel (they can be set [here](http://www.youtube.com/account_defaults)). I can't seem to find any API calls that will let me do this. Is there one that I am missing?

I'm currently using version 2, but I would use version 3 if necessary (at least for this information). I'm not using any of the platform specific APIs (such as the .Net API), I am calling directly into the http API.